# Found one strange behavior in webdriver io, .equals method is not working but ' === ' is working in assertion

Tags: javascript, automation, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

Hello I am new to webdriverio automation, and while practice webdriverio, I found one strange behavior.

This is my test code

```
const internetPage = require("../pages/InternetPage"); //Importing InternetPage in javascript

describe("Handling checkboxes", function(){

it("Check page url ", function(){
    browser.url("/");
    expect(browser.getUrl() === ("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/"));
});

it("Should click on checkbox", function(){
   // browser.url("/");
    internetPage.clickOnLink(6);

   // browser.pause(1000);
    internetPage.h3Header.waitForDisplayed();
    internetPage.clickOnCheckBox(1);

    expect(internetPage.getCheckboxElement(1).isSelected() === true);

    /**
     * 
     * FYI :  FOUND SOME ISSUE THAT .equal or .equals () method doesnot work instead use === to compare or check whether the actual value is equals to the expected value
     */

    browser.pause(5000);
});

it("check checkbox page header", function(){
    internetPage.clickOnLink(6);
    internetPage.h3Header.waitForDisplayed();
    const text = internetPage.h3Header.getText();
    expect(text === "Checkboxes");
});

});
```

When i write this block of code my test passes successfully,
however if I use the given code below

```
describe("Handling checkboxes", function(){

it("Check page url ", function(){
    browser.url("/");
    expect(browser.getUrl().equals("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/"));
});

it("Should click on checkbox", function(){
   // browser.url("/");
    internetPage.clickOnLink(6);

   // browser.pause(1000);
    internetPage.h3Header.waitForDisplayed();
    internetPage.clickOnCheckBox(1);

    expect(internetPage.getCheckboxElement(1).isSelected().equals(true));

    /**
     * 
     * FYI :  FOUND SOME ISSUE THAT .equal or .equals () method doesnot work instead use === to compare or check whether the actual value is equals to the expected value
     */

    browser.pause(5000);
});

it("check checkbox page header", function(){
    internetPage.clickOnLink(6);
    internetPage.h3Header.waitForDisplayed();
    const text = internetPage.h3Header.getText();
    expect(text.equals("Checkboxes"));
});

});
```

Then the functionality of my test works correctly, i.e. it launches the browser, it clicks on checkbox and verifies the checkbox is selected or not but shows the given error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye0cO.png)

And my page Object file name InternetPage.js file is given below as

```
class InternetPage{

get h3Header(){
    return $('h3');
}

getLinkElement(index){
    return $(`ul > li:nth-child(${index}) a`);
}

clickOnLink(index){
    this.getLinkElement(index).waitForDisplayed();
    this.getLinkElement(index).click(); 
}

getCheckboxElement(index){
    return $(`form#checkboxes > input:nth-child(${index})`);
}

clickOnCheckBox(index){
    this.getCheckboxElement(index).waitForDisplayed();
    this.getCheckboxElement(index).click();
}
```

}
module.exports = new InternetPage();

I am also attaching my package.json file

```
{
    "name": "new_practice",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@wdio/allure-reporter": "^7.16.13",
        "@wdio/cli": "^7.16.13",
        "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.16.13",
        "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^7.16.13",
        "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.16.13",
        "@wdio/sync": "^7.16.13",
        "chai": "^4.3.4",
        "chai-webdriverio": "^1.0.0",
        "chromedriver": "^97.0.0",
        "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^7.2.6"
    }
}
```

And below is my wdio.config.js file

```
exports.config = {
//
// ====================
// Runner Configuration
// ====================
//
//
// ==================
// Specify Test Files
// ==================
// Define which test specs should run. The pattern is relative to the directory
// from which `wdio` was called.
//
// The specs are defined as an array of spec files (optionally using wildcards
// that will be expanded). The test for each spec file will be run in a separate
// worker process. In order to have a group of spec files run in the same worker
// process simply enclose them in an array within the specs array.
//
// If you are calling `wdio` from an NPM script (see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script),
// then the current working directory is where your `package.json` resides, so `wdio`
// will be called from there.
//
specs: [
    './test/specs/**/*.js'
],
// Patterns to exclude.
exclude: [
    // 'path/to/excluded/files'
],
//
// ============
// Capabilities
// ============
// Define your capabilities here. WebdriverIO can run multiple capabilities at the same
// time. Depending on the number of capabilities, WebdriverIO launches several test
// sessions. Within your capabilities you can overwrite the spec and exclude options in
// order to group specific specs to a specific capability.
//
// First, you can define how many instances should be started at the same time. Let's
// say you have 3 different capabilities (Chrome, Firefox, and Safari) and you have
// set maxInstances to 1; wdio will spawn 3 processes. Therefore, if you have 10 spec
// files and you set maxInstances to 10, all spec files will get tested at the same time
// and 30 processes will get spawned. The property handles how many capabilities
// from the same test should run tests.
//
maxInstances: 10,
//
// If you have trouble getting all important capabilities together, check out the
// Sauce Labs platform configurator - a great tool to configure your capabilities:
// https://saucelabs.com/platform/platform-configurator
//
capabilities: [{

    // maxInstances can get overwritten per capability. So if you have an in-house Selenium
    // grid with only 5 firefox instances available you can make sure that not more than
    // 5 instances get started at a time.
    maxInstances: 5,
    //
    browserName: 'chrome',
    acceptInsecureCerts: true
    // If outputDir is provided WebdriverIO can capture driver session logs
    // it is possible to configure which logTypes to include/exclude.
    // excludeDriverLogs: ['*'], // pass '*' to exclude all driver session logs
    // excludeDriverLogs: ['bugreport', 'server'],
}],
//
// ===================
// Test Configurations
// ===================
// Define all options that are relevant for the WebdriverIO instance here
//
// Level of logging verbosity: trace | debug | info | warn | error | silent
logLevel: 'info',
//
// Set specific log levels per logger
// loggers:
// - webdriver, webdriverio
// - @wdio/browserstack-service, @wdio/devtools-service, @wdio/sauce-service
// - @wdio/mocha-framework, @wdio/jasmine-framework
// - @wdio/local-runner
// - @wdio/sumologic-reporter
// - @wdio/cli, @wdio/config, @wdio/utils
// Level of logging verbosity: trace | debug | info | warn | error | silent
// logLevels: {
//     webdriver: 'info',
//     '@wdio/appium-service': 'info'
// },
//
// If you only want to run your tests until a specific amount of tests have failed 
 use
// bail (default is 0 - don't bail, run all tests).
bail: 0,
//
// Set a base URL in order to shorten url command calls. If your `url` parameter 
 starts
// with `/`, the base url gets prepended, not including the path portion of your 
 baseUrl.
// If your `url` parameter starts without a scheme or `/` (like `some/path`), the 
 base url
// gets prepended directly.
//  baseUrl: 'https://www.amazon.ca/',
baseUrl: 'https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/',
trainerName : "Rutu",
//
// Default timeout for all waitFor* commands.
waitforTimeout: 10000,
//
// Default timeout in milliseconds for request
// if browser driver or grid doesn't send response
connectionRetryTimeout: 120000,
//
// Default request retries count
connectionRetryCount: 3,
//
// Test runner services
// Services take over a specific job you don't want to take care of. They enhance
// your test setup with almost no effort. Unlike plugins, they don't add new
// commands. Instead, they hook themselves up into the test process.
services: ['chromedriver'],

// Framework you want to run your specs with.
// The following are supported: Mocha, Jasmine, and Cucumber
// see also: https://webdriver.io/docs/frameworks
//
// Make sure you have the wdio adapter package for the specific framework installed
// before running any tests.
framework: 'mocha',
//
// The number of times to retry the entire specfile when it fails as a whole
// specFileRetries: 1,
//
// Delay in seconds between the spec file retry attempts
// specFileRetriesDelay: 0,
//
// Whether or not retried specfiles should be retried immediately or deferred to the 
end of the queue
// specFileRetriesDeferred: false,
//
// Test reporter for stdout.
// The only one supported by default is 'dot'
// see also: https://webdriver.io/docs/dot-reporter
reporters: ['spec'],



//
// Options to be passed to Mocha.
// See the full list at http://mochajs.org/
mochaOpts: {
    ui: 'bdd',
    timeout: 60000
},
//
// =====
// Hooks
// =====
// WebdriverIO provides several hooks you can use to interfere with the test process 
 in order to enhance
// it and to build services around it. You can either apply a single function or an 
  array of
// methods to it. If one of them returns with a promise, WebdriverIO will wait until 
 that promise got
// resolved to continue.
/**
 * Gets executed once before all workers get launched.
 * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
 * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
 */
// onPrepare: function (config, capabilities) {
// },
/**
 * Gets executed before a worker process is spawned and can be used to initialise 
  specific service
 * for that worker as well as modify runtime environments in an async fashion.
 * @param  {String} cid      capability id (e.g 0-0)
 * @param  {[type]} caps     object containing capabilities for session that will be 
  spawn in the worker
 * @param  {[type]} specs    specs to be run in the worker process
 * @param  {[type]} args     object that will be merged with the main configuration 
  once worker is initialised
 * @param  {[type]} execArgv list of string arguments passed to the worker process
 */
// onWorkerStart: function (cid, caps, specs, args, execArgv) {
// },
/**
 * Gets executed just before initialising the webdriver session and test framework. 
  It allows you
 * to manipulate configurations depending on the capability or spec.
 * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
 * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
 * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that are to be run
 * @param {String} cid worker id (e.g. 0-0)
 */
// beforeSession: function (config, capabilities, specs, cid) {
// },
/**
 * Gets executed before test execution begins. At this point you can access to all 
  global
 * variables like `browser`. It is the perfect place to define custom commands.
 * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
 * @param {Array.<String>} specs        List of spec file paths that are to be run
 * @param {Object}         browser      instance of created browser/device session
 */
// before: function (capabilities, specs) {
// },
/**
 * Runs before a WebdriverIO command gets executed.
 * @param {String} commandName hook command name
 * @param {Array} args arguments that command would receive
 */
// beforeCommand: function (commandName, args) {
// },
/**
 * Hook that gets executed before the suite starts
 * @param {Object} suite suite details
 */
// beforeSuite: function (suite) {
// },
/**
 * Function to be executed before a test (in Mocha/Jasmine) starts.
 */
beforeTest: function () {

    const chai = require('chai');
    const chaiWebdriver = require('chai-webdriverio').default;
    chai.use(chaiWebdriver(browser));

    global.assert = chai.assert;
    global.should = chai.should;
    global.expect = chai.expect;
},
/**
 * Hook that gets executed _before_ a hook within the suite starts (e.g. runs before 
  calling
 * beforeEach in Mocha)
 */
// beforeHook: function (test, context) {
// },
/**
 * Hook that gets executed _after_ a hook within the suite starts (e.g. runs after 
  calling
 * afterEach in Mocha)
 */
// afterHook: function (test, context, { error, result, duration, passed, retries }) {
// },
/**
 * Function to be executed after a test (in Mocha/Jasmine only)
 * @param {Object}  test             test object
 * @param {Object}  context          scope object the test was executed with
 * @param {Error}   result.error     error object in case the test fails, otherwise 
  `undefined`
 * @param {Any}     result.result    return object of test function
 * @param {Number}  result.duration  duration of test
 * @param {Boolean} result.passed    true if test has passed, otherwise false
 * @param {Object}  result.retries   informations to spec related retries, e.g. `{ 
  attempts: 0, limit: 0 }`
 */
// afterTest: function(test, context, { error, result, duration, passed, retries }) {
// },


/**
 * Hook that gets executed after the suite has ended
 * @param {Object} suite suite details
 */
// afterSuite: function (suite) {
// },
/**
 * Runs after a WebdriverIO command gets executed
 * @param {String} commandName hook command name
 * @param {Array} args arguments that command would receive
 * @param {Number} result 0 - command success, 1 - command error
 * @param {Object} error error object if any
 */
// afterCommand: function (commandName, args, result, error) {
// },
/**
 * Gets executed after all tests are done. You still have access to all global 
  variables from
 * the test.
 * @param {Number} result 0 - test pass, 1 - test fail
 * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
 * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that ran
 */
// after: function (result, capabilities, specs) {
// },
/**
 * Gets executed right after terminating the webdriver session.
 * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
 * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
 * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that ran
 */
// afterSession: function (config, capabilities, specs) {
// },
/**
 * Gets executed after all workers got shut down and the process is about to exit. An 
  error
 * thrown in the onComplete hook will result in the test run failing.
 * @param {Object} exitCode 0 - success, 1 - fail
 * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
 * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
 * @param {<Object>} results object containing test results
 */
// onComplete: function(exitCode, config, capabilities, results) {
// },
/**
* Gets executed when a refresh happens.
* @param {String} oldSessionId session ID of the old session
* @param {String} newSessionId session ID of the new session
*/
//onReload: function(oldSessionId, newSessionId) {
//}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

I am afraid the format of assertions you are using is not as per the library documentation. From the documentation [here](https://github.com/marcodejongh/chai-webdriverio), there seems to be no easy way to assert the current URL. Maybe you can check the assertion library provided by webdriverio itself and documentation can be found [here](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/expect-webdriverio).

Comment: thank-you I will try the solution by reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code and you can see the result-

await expect(text).toHaveText("Checkboxes")